# Does government play a genuinely significant role in history, or is it simply a tool for interest groups to apply force on their behalf?

Tags: government

Has government ever played a truly significant role in historical events, or does it mostly rubberstamp things that nongovernmental entities would do anyway?

After all, Manorialism was a social safety net very similar to the modern welfare state. As an example, was the transition ftom feudalism to liberalism a key event in world history, or were the freedoms serfs won gradual change that mostly had to do with economic and demographic factors unrelated to politics?

Comment: This strikes me as a matter of perspectives. The government often were the biggest interest group around.

Comment: I don't think that's an accurate reading of history. Hunter gatherer societies were driven by the need for different interest groups or individuals cooperate to secure food and land. This behavior still existed despite lack of a functioning state. The premodern "states" that later came about were highly disorganized and dysfunctional- see for example the power struggles and truces that held together the Roman Empire, which only gave the illusion of centralized authority.

Comment: What is the difference between government playing a role and government as the tool by which interest groups play a role?

Comment: I have to say, your second paragraph expresses a dualisim between the people and the government that is at odds with the dominant (Classical) Liberal view of government. To someone such as myself brought up under that view, the difference between "people acting in concert" and a "government" is merely one of semantics.

Comment: ...er yeah. What @MarkC.Wallace just said. :-)

Comment: @MarkC There is none. Government is a collective hallucination.

Comment: Hallucination with a monopoly on the use of force.

Comment: Not exactly. The government is not a homogenous entity. The things we call "corruption", "partisanism", "misgovernance", the "deep state", etc are simply the embodiment of different factions within "government".

Comment: @mustang If government is a collective illusion, then so is religion, nationality and the community of people who smoke whatever you're smoking :p.

Comment: Not necessarily because none of those things pretend to be a centralized monopoly on force in a geographic area, with coherent and non-conflicting goals and motives, capable of substantially influencing society in ways nongovernmental entities could not.

Comment: Even the far right doesn't claim that inhabitants of the welfare state are chattel; there is, for example, effectively no restriction on moving to another state.  And your comment "Not exactly...." answers your question.

Comment: "there is, for example, effectively no restriction on moving to another state". Are you talking about American "states" or nationstates? If the latter, then yes, but only because governments are unable or unwilling to control their borders. I don't think you've established that governments can meaningfully be considered a monopoly or near monopoly on the use of force, because every government has extensive corruption and internal conflict. For example, the government sells most of the illegal drugs.

Comment: Can we put a pin in this nonsense? If this fellow wants an aimless political discussion there a lot of places for that, which aren't here.

Comment: I'm just saying that "goverment" is a hallucination and has never existed as a monopoly on the use of force. Very reasonable premise

Answer (score 2):

One of the arguments Barbara Tuchman makes in [The March of Folly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345308239) was that England's loss of its North American colonies in the American Revolution was chiefly due to how their Parliamentary system was working at the time. Basically, it was easier for individual members to get re-elected with tough talk than to argue that it might be better to reach some accommodation with the colonists.

Even without that argument, if you read some of the prewar documents on both sides its pretty clear that the base of the disagreement was over government, and if some arrangement like the [Dominion system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion) had been offered early enough, it would have almost certainly been found acceptable.

Comment: The end result was America adopting a very minimal state for decades until the rise of interest group politics. One could say that government mattered, in a way, but only because of foregone possibilities.

Comment: Hamilton and Washington would disagree about the minimal state. And Jefferson was just as much an interest group as any other; the Democratic Republicans wanted to create a nation of slavery, deficit spending, anti-British, pro-French aristocrats.

Comment: But elections in the early US "state" were decided by which party supplied the most alcohol to voters.